# How to print only datalabel out of whole scandata?

Tags: c#, barcode-scanner

I am a new bee to C# programming. I have a zebra bar code scanner. I made a C# code according to the software user manual.  I am able to print the scandata. However this data consist of all the information about the scanner. It has serial number,module number,GUID,datatype and datalabel.

This datalabel is the information about the bar code. I am interested in this datalabel only. I need to develop further code using this datalabel.

How can I print only the datalabel?.

Here I am attaching my code. Thank you.

```
namespace ConsoleApp_scandata
{
  class Program
  {
    //declare the core scanner class 
    static CCoreScannerClass cCoreScannerClass;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        cCoreScannerClass = new CoreScanner.CCoreScannerClass();

        //CALL OPEN API
        short[] scannerTypes = new short[1];        //scanner types intrested in
        scannerTypes[0] = 1;                        // set all scanner types to 1
        short numberOfScannerTypes = 1;             // size of the scanner type array 
        int status;                                 // Extend API return code

        cCoreScannerClass.Open(0, scannerTypes, numberOfScannerTypes, out status);

        if (status == 0)
            Console.WriteLine("CoreScanner API OPEN");
        else
            Console.WriteLine("CoreScanner API CLOSED");

        // Lists all scanners connected to the host computer.
        // will return nothing

        short numberOfScanners;
        int[] connectedScannerIDList = new int[255];

        string outXML;

        cCoreScannerClass.GetScanners(out numberOfScanners, connectedScannerIDList, out outXML, out status);

        //below does not work because string is an xml file and is never NULL
        Console.WriteLine(outXML);
        // Console.WriteLine(outXML.ToString()); 
        cCoreScannerClass.BarcodeEvent += new _ICoreScannerEvents_BarcodeEventEventHandler(OnBarcodeEvent);
        int opcode = 1001;
        string inXML = "<inArgs>" +
            "<cmdArgs>" +
            "<arg-int>1</arg-int>" +
            "<arg-int>1</arg-int>" +
            "</cmdArgs>" +
            "</inArgs>";
        cCoreScannerClass.ExecCommand(opcode, ref inXML, out outXML, out status);

        opcode = 2011;
        inXML = "<inArgs>" +
           "<scannerID>1</scannerID>" +
              "</inArgs>";
        cCoreScannerClass.ExecCommand(opcode, ref inXML, out outXML, out status);
       

        while (true)
        {
            Console.Read();
        }
        
    }

    private static void OnBarcodeEvent(short eventType, ref string pscanData)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Scannner Event! Scan Data: " + pscanData);
    }
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you please show the code where you print the outArgs. Thanks

Comment: I am just printing pscandata. Console.WriteLine("Scannner Event! Scan Data: " + pscanData);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Load `pscanData` in the `XmlDocument`and your are ready to go, just copy this code:

---

```
private static void OnBarcodeEvent(short eventType, ref string pscanData)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Scannner Event! Scan Data: " + pscanData);

    XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();

    //xmlDoc.LoadXml(pscanData); //You should use this line as far as your XML tags are correct
    xmlDoc.LoadXml("<scandata>" +

                   "<modeldata>" +
                   "099909" +
                   "</modeldata>" +

                   "<datalabel>" +
                   "0x68 0x74 0x74" +
                   "</datalabel>" +

                   "</scandata>"); //I use this harcoded XML because I don't have your pscanData, just delete this line and uncoment the one above

    XmlNodeList datalabel = xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("datalabel");
    XmlNode allInDataLabel = datalabel.Item(0);
    string whatDatalabelContains = allInDataLabel.InnerText;

    Console.WriteLine("Datalabel: " + ToText(whatDatalabelContains));
}
```

---

**Edit: Hex to text**

---

```
private static string ToText(string yourHex)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    string[] dataArr = yourHex.Split(new char[] { ' ' });

    for (int i = 0; i < dataArr.Length; i++)
    {
        sb.Append(Char.ConvertFromUtf32(Convert.ToInt32(dataArr[i], 16)));
    }

    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Can we print the contents of the variable    whatDatalabelContains    in text format.

Comment: Do you mean with `text format` as a `string`? What would your expected output look like? @Mohan

Comment: The data in the variable   whatDatalabelContains  is in hex format. I need this data in human readable format.

Comment: @Mohan Look at the edited answer. Tell me if it works

Comment: Do you know how can I port the VS2019 C# console project (.NET Framework)  to linux?.

Comment: @Mohan I'm not really familiar with linux but maybe this helps: [enter link description here][1]


  [1]: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/linux

Comment: @ Adrian, How to implement above concept of separating xml data in C++. I just copied the same code in C++. however it is throwing errors for the all lines. How to implement in C++. Thank you.